# ASP.NET link button Server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net, non-well-formed

Im trying to add a button in my grid view that will redirect me to another page and pass the id of the movie.
This is my code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                     PostBackUrl="~/Add/CheckMovie.aspx?movie=<%#Eval("mov_id")%>" 
                />
```

A while back in a different app I used similar code and it worked fine

```
<a href="editUser.aspx?usr=<%# Eval("usr") %>"><%# Eval("usr") %></a>
```

Is it because Im using a different tag, or maybe because of the url ?

Comment: I'm pretty confident its because you're using the <%#%> tags in an ASP control (asp:Button). Use a HTML button instead - let me just double check something i wrote the other week. Had a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Add/CheckMovie.aspx?movie=" + Eval("mov_id") %>'
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm, I just had to ad .ToString()

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you get the value of `mov_id` you may be better adding the code to the `page_load` method, something like this

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" PostBackUrl="" />
```

Code Behind

```
Button1.PostBackUrl = "~/Add/CheckMovie.aspx?movie=" + mov_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. The grid view is bound to a table and Im getting the value of mov_id from there.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comment above, its because of the server tag inside the ASp:Button control. You can change it to a HTML button like so:

```
<button class="button" id="submitreorder" onclick="parent.location='<%=ResolveUrl("~/order/ShoppingCart") %>/delete/<%# Eval("Item_ID") %>'">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why it was not working and never realized that it might be because Im using asp tag.

Comment: yeah, its tripped me up before! no worries :)